# Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: visual-studio-2008, forms, c#-3.0, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.1

Error when trying to display the form designer.

**See picture of the error:**

[image]

**Code of the screen:**

```
public partial class frmCanalVenda : frmEdit
{
    public frmCanalVenda(CanalVenda canal, Cliente cli)
        : base(canal)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bdsCliente.DataSource = cli;
        eabBar.ReadOnlyView = false;
    }

    private void frmCanalVenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            bdsAgrupamento.DataSource = Agrupamento.GetAll(DatabaseAFV.Connection);
            bdsCanal.DataSource = Canal.GetAll(DatabaseAFV.Connection);
            bdsSubCanal.DataSource = SubCanal.GetAll(DatabaseAFV.Connection);
            bdsEspecializacao.DataSource = Especializacao.GetAll(DatabaseAFV.Connection);
            bdsOperacao.DataSource = Operacao.GetAll(DatabaseAFV.Connection);
            bdsPorte.DataSource = Porte.GetAll(DatabaseAFV.Connection);
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

**Text of image**

> To prevent possible data loss before
>   loading the designer, the following
>   errors must be resolved:
>
> Value does not fall within the
>   expected range.
>
> Instances of this error (1)
>
> 1. Hide Call Stack    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>      errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32
>      hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetFileDocData(String
>      fileName, FileAccess access, String
>      createTemplate, Boolean addToHostList,
>      Boolean nestedItem) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetChildDocData(String
>      name, FileAccess access, String
>      createTemplate) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.GetResourceDocData(CultureInfo
>      info, FileAccess access) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.System.ComponentModel.Design.IResourceService.GetResourceReader(CultureInfo
>      info) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ResourceCodeDomSerializer.SerializationResourceManager.GetMetadata()
>      at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ResourceCodeDomSerializer.SerializationResourceManager.GetMetadataEnumerator()
>      at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertiesFromResources(IDesignerSerializationManager
>      manager, Object value, Attribute[]
>      filter) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>      manager, CodeTypeDeclaration
>      declaration) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>      manager) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>      serializationManager) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost
>      host)

Comment: Why not post the _text_ of the error? The picture as it appears is not legible.

Comment: @Oded: if you zoom the page it becomes readable :p

Comment: @Kornelije Petak - And you still can't copy/paste that if you wanted to.

Answer (score 50):

A hail mary: restarting Visual Studio worked for me.

Comment: Haha this is almost in line with "reboot" or "reinstall windows". Yet it worked, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be caused by changes to the project properties / settings file. If recent changes have been made to the settings do the following:-

1. Check that the settings xml file does not contain any unwanted elements.
2. Close Visual Studio and restart VS and open the project

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Our guy, this was six months ago, not even remember how I resolved it.

Comment: I use git, I did checkout older commits, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unload project and reload project worked for me.