# Bluetooth Low-energy Advertising Data Restriction in Windows 10 API

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having an issue with the [BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection.BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894230.aspx) from the Windows 10 Bluetooth Low-energy (BLE) API.

If I check the length of the `IBuffer` member `Data` using this code:

```
 var myDataSection = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection();
 Debug.WriteLine($"Data Capacity: {myDataSection.Data.Capacity}"); //Looks like SO needs to update for C# 6.0
```

I get the expected output:

> Data Capacity: 29

*For more info on BLE packets, I recommend visiting [this great blog post](http://j2abro.blogspot.com/2014/06/understanding-bluetooth-advertising.html).*

Now let' say I've declared a `byte[]` called `myPayload` which is 29 bytes long. The following code throws an exception:

```
 DataWriter writer = new DataWriter();
 writer.WriteBytes(myPayload);
 myDataSection.Data = writer.DetachBuffer(); //throws ArgumentException
```

The `ArgumentException` very helpfully suggests that

> "Value does not fall within the expected range."

In fact, any size for `myPayload` of **20+ bytes** results in the same error. If I make it **19 bytes** long, however, I get no errors.

*Yes, I was very upset when [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15955549/4163002) did not help.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really sad...but I actually just miscounted the number of bytes I was adding. **29 bytes** does work. 30 does not. **This is not an API issue.**

```
 static readonly byte[] myPayload =  
{0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xAB,0xCD,0xEF, //8 bytes
 0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xAB,0xCD,0xEF, //8 bytes
 0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xAB,0xCD,0xEF, //8 bytes
 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}; //5 bytes Total:29 bytes
```

...will work just fine.

Comment: In the future in a similar situation you may benefit from specifying the length of the array in the declaration `static readonly byte[29] myPayload = ...`

Comment: @Daniel I like the idea, but your syntax needs a slight modification: `static readonly byte[] myPayload = new byte[29]{/* 29 bytes of data here */}`

Comment: Not surprising that I got the syntax off I didn't test it, but you see the idea. For more options you can view [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)